# Is there a Difference between Splitting on Character to Splitting on Phrase

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, split

Is there any difference in the output of these two functions? I have a text editor I'm modifying on a website. The editor currently splits by character but I am switching it to split by a word or phrase.

**Split by Character**

```
string words = "word1*word2*word3*word4";
string[] collectionofWords = words.Split('*');
```

**Split by Word**

```
string words = "word1***word2***word3***word4";
string[] collectionofWords = words.Split(new string[] { "***" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

**Do these functions work exactly the same even in difficult scenarios?**

In my example above they appear to word identically but what if there was empty data (EG1) or what if there was characters at the beginning or end of the string (EG2) would these functions still produce identical results?

**Is there any scenario where these two functions would produce different results given the same data being passed in?**

**EG1**

```
string words = "word1*word2**word4";
string words = "word1***word2******word4";
```

**EG2**

```
string words = "*word1*word2*word3*word4*";
string words = "***word1***word2***word3***word4***";
```

Comment: Do you know that the source code of the NET Framework is available at [this address](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/)?

Comment: Its not an operator, im just using * and *** to split the string into an array

Comment: You should clarify your question you should use different identifiers. As it stands it looks like you're asking if splitting on one asterisk is the same as splitting on three, which is not the case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In short: no. There is no functional difference between splitting using the character overload and splitting using a string overload. However splitting with a string should be slightly less efficient than due to more checks required.

Also as far as I know they would function identically under the same circumstances since they are basically the same code just with different comparisons.

Comment: thank you that was what i wanted to know, besides preformance there is know actual difference in the data that is returned to the array

Comment: "basically the same code" - actually, from reading string class just now, this is not true. those are two different methods, each one having different dependencies.

Comment: The problem is that the two examples given use _different delimiters_, so there is a difference.

Comment: besides the delimiters its the same output?

Answer (score 0):

If you are afraid of different results you can use another method splitting on a regex match:

```
string words = "word1*word2*word3*word4";
string words2 = "word1***word2***word3***word4";

string[] arr = Regex.Split(words, @"\*+");
string[] arr2 = Regex.Split(words2, @"\*+");

if (arr.SequenceEqual(arr2))
    Console.WriteLine("Arrays are equal");
```

Comment: The question is if it's feasible, you don't want to protect something that can't happen..

Answer (score 0):

In contrary to what suggested here, and from [string class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,64bbfbd0ad12230d) implementation, those are two different methods, with different dependencies.

By design the expected output should be the same from [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) (putting aside the performance differences).